# How to make full bleed layout (divided in two half's)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to split the page in two section.
Based on either one of them the height of other section should expand and collapse.

I tried to make this layout but not able to predict what is the problem in it.
Here is the link of the fiddle.

I don't want to apply some min-height on the container as content can increase or decrease, if I don't use min-height entire content is getting hidden between header and footer.

https://jsfiddle.net/j4vcLbaL/1/

HTML

```
    <header>I am Header</header>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="page-wrapper">

    <div class="left-col">
      <div class="section">
        <div class="icons">
          <ul>
            <li class="fa fa-cloud">1</li>
            <li class="fa fa-cloud">2</li>
            <li class="fa fa-cloud">3</li>
            <li class="fa fa-cloud">4</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            ____Left Column----
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting                 industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text               ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type             and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not               only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">

      <div class="content">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting                 industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text               ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type             and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not               only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting                 industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text               ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type             and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not               only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<footer>
  I am Footer
</footer>
```

Css

```
  .page-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  min-height:100px;
}

#content{
  margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
  }

.left-col{
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
}
.section {
  clear:both;
  padding-right:10px;
}
.icons{
  position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 64px;
    z-index: 1;
        background: #999;
}

.text{
  position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    padding-left: 64px;
}

.right-col{
    background: #fff;
    color:#000;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j4vcLbaL/1/

Comment: Don't use position: absolute; At least with columns when working with responsive layout. Use float: left; or display: inline-block;

Comment: Added Code Along with the post

Comment: As @lonut mentions, you can't use `position: absolute;` to get the result you are after. Depending on the browsers you are looking to target `flexbox` will allow you to get the result: https://jsfiddle.net/bouLqmx9/

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Flex Box can do the trick but only problem with that is browser support issues :(

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Found Polyfill for it https://github.com/10up/flexibility

Answer (score 0):

Here is a updated layout you can test columns with the content and height of columns will extend equal.

**I think this code will help to you!**

```css
/* ================================================================= */
/* Partial Section                                    */
/* ================================================================= */

.partial_section {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #2196F3;
}
.partial_section::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.partial_section::after {
    background: #000d21;
}
.partial_section::after {
    right: 0;
}
.content_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 80px 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.ps_column {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.section_half.ps_column {
    width: 48%;
}
.ps-title {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
}
.ps-title h3 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}
.ps-content-wrap {
    padding: 40px;
}
.ps-content {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
}
header {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
footer {
    background-color: #E91E63;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- Partial Section Wrapper -->
 <header>
  <div class="ps-title">
   <h3>Header section</h3>
  </div>
 </header>
 <div class="partial_section section-border-bottom">
  <!-- Section content -->
  <div class="content_wrapper">
   <!-- Section Column -->
   <div class="section_half ps_column">
    <div class="ps-content-wrap" style="color: #ffffff;">
     <div class="ps-title">
      <h3>COLUMN LEFT</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="ps-content">
      <p>Praesent gravida pretium mauris a cursus. Proin feugiat fringilla tristique. In congue libero eleifend, condimentum tortor vitae, viverra purus. Integer at fringilla sem. Donec vel posuere tortor. Sed a tempor velit. Quisque non elit ligula. Praesent
       velit massa, tempor non vulputate id, iaculis eget nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>

      <p>Nullam scelerisque arcu dui, sed feugiat nunc dictum at. Mauris porttitor enim et massa dictum mattis. Cras non porttitor magna, nec aliquet ipsum. Nulla ac diam gravida, congue quam in, porta lorem. Integer vestibulum tempor urna sed porttitor.
       Phasellus pellentesque purus id suscipit fringilla.</p>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <!-- Section Column -->
   <div class="section_half ps_column">
    <div class="ps-content-wrap" style="color: #ffffff;">
     <div class="ps-title">
      <h3>COLUMN RIGHT</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="ps-content">
      <p>Praesent gravida pretium mauris a cursus. Proin feugiat fringilla tristique. In congue libero eleifend, condimentum tortor vitae, viverra purus. Integer at fringilla sem. Donec vel posuere tortor. Sed a tempor velit. Quisque non elit ligula. Praesent
       velit massa, tempor non vulputate id, iaculis eget nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>

      <p>Nullam scelerisque arcu dui, sed feugiat nunc dictum at. Mauris porttitor enim et massa dictum mattis. Cras non porttitor magna, nec aliquet ipsum. Nulla ac diam gravida, congue quam in, porta lorem. Integer vestibulum tempor urna sed porttitor.
       Phasellus pellentesque purus id suscipit fringilla.</p>

      <p>Nullam scelerisque arcu dui, sed feugiat nunc dictum at. Mauris porttitor enim et massa dictum mattis. Cras non porttitor magna, nec aliquet ipsum. Nulla ac diam gravida, congue quam in, porta lorem. Integer vestibulum tempor urna sed porttitor.
       Phasellus pellentesque purus id suscipit fringilla.</p>

      <p>Nullam scelerisque arcu dui, sed feugiat nunc dictum at. Mauris porttitor enim et massa dictum mattis. Cras non porttitor magna, nec aliquet ipsum. Nulla ac diam gravida, congue quam in, porta lorem. Integer vestibulum tempor urna sed porttitor.
       Phasellus pellentesque purus id suscipit fringilla.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <footer>
  <div class="ps-title">
   <h3>Footer section</h3>
  </div>
 </footer>
```

Comment: This Layout Fails if right column has less content than left column

Comment: Do you want columns height extends with content?

Comment: Code has undated you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `flex-box` for the same:

```
CSS:

.page-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position:relative;
  min-height:100px;
}

#content{
  margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
  }
.left-col{
    background: #ccc;
    width: 40%;
}
.section {
  clear:both;
  padding-right:10px;
}
.icons{
  position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 64px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #999;
}

.text{
  position: relative;
      width: 100%;
}

.right-col{
    background: #fff;
    color:#000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a5puum99/1/